# Gecko Driver in Mac

Tags: maven, selenium

I am new to geckodriver in selenium. I am using MAC (IOS) and written the code as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/geckodriver");

driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
```

This gives an error message that

> The driver executable does not exist on the specified location.

even though its on the same location.

tried with adding .exe at the end of geckodriver. (still does not work)

Tried setting system.setproperty as

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/gecoDriver/geckodriver");
```

this does work but open a blank firefox page and does not show the URL.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your first approach. Please change the geckodriver path.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/gecoDriver/geckodriver");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
```

**Explanation:**

System.getProperty("user.dir") gives you the project path. If your **geckodriver.exe** is placed in the src folder then you can set the path as:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/geckodriver");
```

Comment: Many thanks, Monika, tried changing the folder did not work, updated selenium jar files and gecko driver.exe and it worked.

Look like correct jar and change of location and following your suggestion worked.